# Is it possible to hide a certain HTML element from a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a webpage which I want to embed a video on that can't be seen by Chrome Extensions. I don't want to hide the element to the user, just hide it from the extension's view.

Is this even possible, and if so, how would I go about it?

Comment: Depending on the target extension's approach to processing DOM, it may fail if you put your video inside an iframe and/or inside a ShadowDOM. However if the extension is written with these things in mind it'll be able to find the element no matter what you do.

Comment: So far I have been embedding the video inside an iFrame, and the extension still gets to it.

Comment: You can use flash or java widget to show the video.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: @TheDeveloperNextDoor look here: http://www.flv-media-player.com/ however Flash support is disabled by default in most browsers. It is a dirty workaround

Comment: What about WebGL? Something like [that](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_video_panorama_equirectangular).